# GNU parallel dynamically distribute load based on "backpressure"

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

Consider that I have a program `my-runner` that exhibits the following behaviour:

1. It takes its input from stdin line-by-line
2. It executes some operation for each input line, as soon as it receives the input line
3. The execution time for each input is widely varied: some input lines might take 100x or 1000x longer to execute than other input lines.
4. It has a slow startup time

Now the challenge is to solve for the combination of point 3 & 4:

- I can address point 3 by running with small batches (e.g. `<input> | parallel --pipe -N 1 my-runner`), but then the slow startup time dominates the overall runtime
- I can address point 4 by running few jobs with big inputs. (e.g. `<input> | parallel --pipe -N 100 my-runner`). But now the overall runtime will be dominated by the unlucky job that receives slow lines.

So what I'm looking for is a way to run `my-runner` in parallel, such that:

- lines are fed one at a time to the runners
- When a runner finishes processing a line, it receives a new line without needing to restart

In pseudo-code I imagine this to be something like this:

```
runners = [my-runner, my-runner]

foreach line from stdin 
    runner = waitForNextAvailableRunner()
    runner.stdin.sendLine(line)
    runner.stdout.whenLineProcessingFinished(markRunnerAsAvailable)
```

Is something like this at all possible with `parallel`? Or are there other well-known tools available for this kind of load balancing?

---

UPDATE:

Just to clarify with a simple example what I'm after.

Let's say that we want to run 2 tasks in parallel, startup time is 2 seconds, and we receive tasks with these runtime lengths:

- t1: 4s
- t2: 1s
- t3: 1s
- t4: 1s
- t5: 1s

If every worker receives/takes a task when they're ready for more work, without restarting in the middle, then the total runtime would be 6 seconds:

| time | worker1 | worker2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | startup | startup |
| 1 | startup | startup |
| 2 | t1 | t2 |
| 3 | t1 | t3 |
| 4 | t1 | t4 |
| 5 | t1 | t5 |
| 6 | done | done |

Running a job per task (N=1) is way worse due to restarts:

| time | slot1 | slot2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | startup | startup |
| 1 | startup | startup |
| 2 | t1 | t2 |
| 3 | t1 | startup |
| 4 | t1 | startup |
| 5 | t1 | t3 |
| 6 | startup | startup |
| 7 | startup | startup |
| 8 | t4 | t5 |
| 9 | done | done |

And so is running 2 jobs with evenly distributed inputs (e.g. round-robin), due to unevenly distributed work loads:

| time | worker1 | worker2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | startup | startup |
| 1 | startup | startup |
| 2 | t1 | t2 |
| 3 | t1 | t4 |
| 4 | t1 | done |
| 5 | t1 |  |
| 6 | t3 |  |
| 7 | t5 |  |
| 8 | done |  |

Comment: Is there any possibility of sorting the input lines by time likely needed for processing, i.e. starting longest-running jobs first?

Comment: Not in the general case, that'd be my plan B. For a bit of context: I'm writing a test runner where the test paths are simply piped in. I don't want to build in parallel execution when this can already be achieved by combining with other tools, like `parallel`, so instead I want to recommend my users to use these. I.e. they can do `echo testFiles | parallel my-runner`. I _could_ ask them to provide slow tests first, but that puts an extra (contextual) burden on the end user. Preferably I'd tell them to just run something like `echo testFiles | parallel --with-backpressure my-runner`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `--round-robin`. `--round-robin` gives input to the process that is ready to read. In other words: It does *not* spread input evenly.

The below shows `--roundrobin` gives the job to the one worker that is willing to take it.

Worker 1 has a delay of 1 second per job + the input.

Worker 10 has a delay of 10 seconds per job + the input.

So we expect to see more jobs taken by worker 1 than by worker 10 on average.

```
rr() {
    perl -ne '$|=1; $delay='$1';$ms=<>; $job++; print "Delay $delay; Job $job; Sleep $ms"; select(undef, undef, undef, $delay+$ms/1000);'
}
export -f rr

seq 100 | shuf | perl -pe 'BEGIN{$a=" "x200000}; s/$/$a/' |
    parallel --roundrobin --ll -N1 --pipe -j10 rr {%}
```

Example output:

```
Delay 3; Job 7; Sleep
Delay 5; Job 4; Sleep
Delay 8; Job 3; Sleep
Delay 10; Job 3; Sleep
Delay 9; Job 3; Sleep
Delay 1; Job 14; Sleep
Delay 6; Job 4; Sleep
Delay 2; Job 8; Sleep
Delay 7; Job 4; Sleep
Delay 4; Job 5; Sleep
```

Note how 1 completed 14, whereas 10 only completed 3.

As you can see I add 200 KB of spaces to each line. This is because a pipe will buffer an amount of data. We need to force the pipe to at most buffer a single line: Otherwise more than one job may be given to a worker, and these might both be slow jobs. You might be able to force the pipes to buffer less data in a different way (eg with `stdbuf`).

Other example:

```
rr() {
    while read i; do
        echo start $i
        sleep $i
        echo end $i
    done
}
export -f rr

echo 10 1.01 1.02 1.03 1.04 1.05 1.06 1.07 | xargs -n1 echo |
    perl -pe 'BEGIN{$a=" "x200000}; s/$/$a/' |
    time parallel -j2 --roundrobin --ll -N1 --pipe rr
```

Most of the jobs will be run by the one that runs short jobs.

Comment: --roundrobin seems to evenly distribute the jobs over the worker, meaning it addresses 4, but not 3. E.g. if I run your example, then the workers with a low timeout finish much earlier than the workers with a high timeout. Some workers end when others still have 90% of their tasks in the queue. This means that the runtime is still dominated by the unlucky worker receiving slow tasks.